# Selective Bloom in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I am trying to make a Neon sign using three.js and I am using BloomPass and emmissive texture to create this effect. I am primarily following this example as I only want One of the models in my scene to glow. ((https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective.html))

The issue I am running in to is that this is occuring.[image]

Some elements in my background model and my pacman glb model are glowing and the neon sign is barely glowing. When I tried to change the color of the neon sign or see any changes to it nothing happens. It also makes my scene super dark, it isn't generally this dark.

This is another example with higher exposure and settings  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrC6v.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUPW9.jpg

An issue I was having before the exposure went really low is that the entire scene had the Bloom effect and was super blurry.

Based on other examples I have written the code with the intention of rendering everything in the scene black and then render the Neon scene with bloom then render everything back to original colors however, this is obviously not working.

[Github](https://github.com/ElijahSchrock/project_get_paid)
*Don't worry about how messy the code is im  just trying everything here lol*

**VERY IMPORTANT**
I have the current code in the NeonSign.js file that is where I have been doing my post processing work. DO NOT use the code in postprocessing.js it is just for reference and is not  correct and will not reproduce this error